# xml parsing in php - getting specific values

Tags: php, xml

New to parsing XML and XML in general... I am working off an example, but there are a few things I cannot figure out :

I am currently using something such as this for values :

```
$order->reference = $doc->getElementsByTagName("reference")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

which I realize is getting the value of the 1st occurrence of x and it works fine.

Now, since `customer` and `purchaser` have the same values within them how can I target one or the other?  There will only be a max of one instance for each.

Also, I expect multiple `<orderItem>` within `<orderItems>`... how can I iterate through these... preferably creating something like an array as I will have no idea how many there will be.

**example xml :**

```
<order>
  <reference/>
  <status>open | request | requested | acceptance | accepted | fulfillment | fulfilled | completion | completed | canceled | failed</status>
  <statusChanged>2010-08-15T00:00:00.000Z</statusChanged>
  <test>true | false</test>
  <due>2010-08-15T00:00:00.000Z</due>
  <returnStatus>none | partial | full</returnStatus>
  <currency/>
  <referrer/>
  <originIp/>
  <total>0.0</total>
  <tax>0.0</tax>
  <shipping>0.0</shipping>
  <sourceName/>
  <sourceKey/>
  <sourceCampaign/>
  <customer>
    <firstName/>
    <lastName/>
    <company/>
    <email/>
    <phoneNumber/>
  </customer>
  <purchaser>
    <firstName/>
    <lastName/>
    <company/>
    <email/>
    <phoneNumber/>
  </purchaser>
  <address>
    <addressLine1/>
    <addressLine2/>
    <city/>
    <region/>
    <regionCustom/>
    <postalCode/>
    <country/>
  </address>
  <orderItems>
    <orderItem>
      <productDisplay/>
      <productName/>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
      <subscriptionReference/>
    </orderItem>
  </orderItems>
  <payments>
    <payment>
      <status>open | request | requested | acceptance | accepted | fulfillment | fulfilled | completion | completed | canceled | failed</status>
      <statusChanged>2010-08-15T00:00:00.000Z</statusChanged>
      <methodType>paypal | creditcard | test | bank | check | purchase-order | free</methodType>
      <declinedReason>internal-error | unsupported-country | expired-card | declined | risk | processor-risk | connection | unknown | cc-address-verification | cc-cvv | voice-auth</declinedReason>
      <currency/>
      <total>0.0</total>
    </payment>
  </payments>
</order>
```

**EDIT :**

Getting no errors yet no values for customer / purchaser.

```
private function parseFsprgOrder($doc) {
    //show values coming in
    echo '<pre>',print_r($doc, 1),'</pre>';

    $order = new FsprgOrder();

    $order->reference = $doc->getElementsByTagName("reference")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->status = $doc->getElementsByTagName("status")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->statusChanged = strtotime($doc->getElementsByTagName("statusChanged")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $order->test = $doc->getElementsByTagName("test")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->due = strtotime($doc->getElementsByTagName("due")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $order->returnStatus = $doc->getElementsByTagName("returnStatus")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->currency = $doc->getElementsByTagName("currency")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->referrer = $doc->getElementsByTagName("referrer")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->originIp = $doc->getElementsByTagName("originIp")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->total = $doc->getElementsByTagName("total")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->tax = $doc->getElementsByTagName("tax")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->shipping = $doc->getElementsByTagName("shipping")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->sourceName = $doc->getElementsByTagName("sourceName")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->sourceKey = $doc->getElementsByTagName("sourceKey")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $order->sourceCampaign = $doc->getElementsByTagName("sourceCampaign")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    //customer info 
    $customerNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("customer")->item(0);

    if($customerNodes->length > 0)
    {
        $customer = new FsprgCustomer();

        $customer->firstName = $customerNodes->getElementsByTagName("firstName")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $customer->lastName = $customerNodes->getElementsByTagName("lastName")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $customer->company = $customerNodes->getElementsByTagName("company")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $customer->email = $customerNodes->getElementsByTagName("email")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $customer->phoneNumber = $customerNodes->getElementsByTagName("phoneNumber")->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $order->customer = $customer;
    }

    //purchaser info
    $purchaserNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("purchaser")->item(0);

    if($purchaserNodes->length > 0)
    {
        $purchaser = new FsprgPurchaser();

        $purchaser->firstName = $purchaserNodes->getElementsByTagName("firstName")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $purchaser->lastName = $purchaserNodes->getElementsByTagName("lastName")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $purchaser->company = $purchaserNodes->getElementsByTagName("company")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $purchaser->email = $purchaserNodes->getElementsByTagName("email")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $purchaser->phoneNumber = $purchaserNodes->getElementsByTagName("phoneNumber")->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $order->purchaser = $purchaser;
    }

    return $order;
}

class FsprgCustomer {
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $company;
    public $email;
    public $phoneNumber;
}

class FsprgPurchaser {
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $company;
    public $email;
    public $phoneNumber;
}

class FsprgOrder {
    public $reference;
    public $status;
    public $statusChanged;
    public $test;
    public $due;
    public $returnStatus;
    public $currency;
    public $referrer;
    public $originIp;
    public $total;
    public $tax;
    public $shipping;
    public $sourceName;
    public $sourceKey;
    public $sourceCampaign;
}
```

Comment: what values you want to get from customer, purchaser and orderitems? Your answer lies in your question.

Comment: No kidding... I know what I want to get... I don't realize how to target them.  I looked at all sort of tutorials, but everything was using simplexml and I am going to stick with the examples provided to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$customerNodes=order->getElemensByTagName('customer');
if($customerNodes->length>0)
    $customer=$customerNodes->item(0);
$purchaseNodes=order->getElemensByTagName('purchase');
if($purchaseNodes->length>0)
    $purchase=$purchaseNodes->item(0);
$orderItemNodes=order->getElemensByTagName('orderItem');
if($orderItemNodes->length>0)
    foreach($orderItemNodes as $orderItemNode){
        //process $orderItemNode    
    }
```

Comment: Trying to incorporate this, but getting an error... I see the logic you are going for though.  Storing 'customer' as its own, if there is anything, then do the same process as I was just within 'customer' only.

Comment: You can get customer, purchase, orderitem from this. next you can access attributes using nodeValue.

Comment: I add my own solution below which works for me - had to make a few changes with yours to get it to work.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [DOMXPath::evaluate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php). This allows you to fetch values from a DOM using XPath expressions.

Fetching a list of nodes:

```
$xpath - new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$nodeList = $xpath->evaluate('/order');
```

Or a scalar value:

```
$xpath - new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$string = $xpath->evaluate('string(/order/customer/firstName)');
```

Comment: I'd like to stick to the same format it is in, but if I can't figure this out will come back to it.  Thanks.

Comment: This is part of the dom extension. Think of it as a powerful version of getElementsByTagName().

Answer (score 0):

```
//customer info 
$customerNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("customer");

if($customerNodes->length > 0)
{
    $customer = new FsprgCustomer();

    $customer->firstName = $customerNodes->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("firstName")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $customer->lastName = $customerNodes->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("lastName")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $customer->company = $customerNodes->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("company")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $customer->email = $customerNodes->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("email")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $customer->phoneNumber = $customerNodes->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("phoneNumber")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $order->customer = $customer;
}
```